# How doest the site counts the visits per day?

Tags: discussion, beta

As pointed out by others, we have some "criteria" in the AREA 51. But they seem to not be the only thing that will count. Although, I think they have some importance for the decision if the site is healthy, and it is worth it to take it to the public beta. I would say we are doing good for most of those criteria, but we lack a lot with the "visits per day". Do we know how this is considered? I mean, there is a certain time between a "visit" and another to be counted as two different ones? I'm trying to be on the site as many times as I can during the day, but I'm not sure if only "refreshing the page" counts or not. Also, they state that a healthy site has 90% of the traffic from search engines, but now we can't have this traffic. So, it's just a consideration for the next phase?

Answer (score 3):

The stats shown on Area51 include 'visits per day' (bottom of dashboard, below). This suggests that a good site should have >1500 visits per day, but any site should have >500 visits per day. The Bioacoustics Site has hovered around 140-170 visits per day.
[image: Area51 Beta Dashboard]

Apparently the 'visits per day' is calculated from google analytics (see [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27926/what-has-happened-to-the-visits-per-day-stats-they-look-unrealistically-low)). I doubt that multiple visits per day (from the same IP address) will count as this would not be a good indicator of success. I greatly appreciate your enthusiasm, and welcome all participation, but encouraging other acousticians to create a daily habit of checking in will lead to more success.

According to [this question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32785/research-about-minimum-requirements-in-beta-sites) on Area51 Meta site, these metrics were created early on with little research to determine their importance. This answer goes on to state that the moderators who decide if a private beta advances to public beta does not rely on these stats. They suggest that # questions asked & # questions answered are helpful indicators of success. *This, of course, begs the question of how 'success' is identified....*

Comment: interesting to see that ~90% of existing non-beta sites have less than 10questions per day https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday